# Cannot run springboot application in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a project for a prospective employer right now written in Java. I had my environment set up and running neatly (meaning I was able to properly run the SpringBootApplication that handled the webpage I am working on when all of the sudden I started receiving this error everytime I tried to run the application:
[Error Message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNAai.png) I have tried ensuring windows is updated, clean installations of VSCode on both my current user account and a new user account, verifying the existence of paths, etc but I have not found anything that will rid me of this error. Please, if anyone has an idea of what I could do to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: You can change the setting `java.debug.settings.console` to `internalConsole` and try again.

Comment: Changing the `java.debug.settings.console` option doesn't seem to be changing anything about how the application runs, unfortunately,

Comment: Maybe you can file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues. Meanwhile, you can attach a sample project or the language server log (trigger command `Java: Open Java Language Server Log File`).

Comment: Instead of image if you copy/paste your error code then it will help users to answer easily